# Send id by get option

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, frameworks

Hello I am developing a application based in AngularJS and Laravel but I have a problem with the AngularJS part.

I have this code

```
$scope.archive = function() {
  var oldnodes = $scope.nodes;
    angular.forEach(oldnodes, function(node) {
    if (node.done) 

        alert(node.id);
        $http.get('http://localhost/copiaAngus/public/deleteSelected/(node.id)').success(function(data)
        {
            alert(node.id);/**Show a id of checkbox selected***/
             $timeout(function() {
                $location.path('/');
              });
        });
    });

};
```

In the alert message you can show the id of the node selected and I don't know how to pass all of id to laravel.

The Laravel part

```
  Route::get("deleteSelected/{id}", function()
    {
        $posts = Nodes::destroy($id);
        return Response::json(array(
            "posts"        =>        $posts
        ));

    });
```

The destroy is working with this form

```
    $posts = Nodes::destroy(1,2);
```

Comment: `$http.get('http://localhost/copiaAngus/public/deleteSelected/'+node.id)`?

Comment: Ok! I try to do this option and isn't working :( I update the question.

Comment: So you want to send all the ids of the nodes that are selected (`node.done == true`) to the server at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to transfer a set of id's to the server. Lets add them to the URL and separate the list with semicolons. So our final URL would look something like this:

```
http://localhost/copiaAngus/public/deleteSelected/1;4;5
```

First we need to change the server-side code to be able to accept this parameter

```
Route::get("deleteSelected/{ids}", function($ids)
{
    $ids_array = explode(';', $ids);
    $posts = Nodes::destroy($ids_array);
    return Response::json(array(
        "posts" => $posts
    ));
});
```

And now, here's how to generate the URL

```
$scope.archive = function() {
    // filter the nodes so we only have the "done" ones
    var nodes = $scope.nodes.filter(function(node){
        return node.done;
    });

    // now build a new array that only contains the ids
    var ids = nodes.map(function(node){
        return node.id;
    });

    $http.get('http://localhost/copiaAngus/public/deleteSelected/'+ids.join(';')).success(function(data){
        alert(data.posts + ' post(s) deleted');
        $timeout(function(){
            $location.path('/');
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand all part of php laravel , in the angularjs part i don't understand why is nodes.map ? The code it's working correctly!

Comment: The [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function lets you loop over an array and create a new one containing the values you return. So out of an array of full node objects we make an array of only ids.